# How to retrieve data using alphanumeric value?

Tags: php

Is it possible to retrieve data using a value that is alphanumeric?

Because whenever my `"product_id"` value is alphanumeric it doesn't work but it only works when the value is numerical.

E.g it only works when the `"product_id" = 1` , but when `"product_id" = 1a` it does not work.

```
// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = $product_id");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $product = array();
        $product["product_id"] = $result["product_id"];
        $product["product_des"] = $result["product_des"];
        $product["price"] = $result["price"];
        $product["qty"] = $result["qty"];
        $product["product_cat"] = $result["product_cat"];
        $product["product_sect"] = $result["product_sect"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // user node
        $response["product"] = array();

        array_push($response["product"], $product);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes; or preferably prepared statements. SQL strings need to be quoted.

E.g.

```
Select * from users where name = chris
```

is invalid SQL. But

```
Select * from users where name = 'chris'
```

would be valid.

So

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = $product_id");
```

Should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = '$product_id'");
```

since you are using `mysql_` functions be sure that `$product_id` is being passed through `mysql_real_escape_string`. Note the warnings on all the `mysql_` function pages as well and consider updating your driver.

With `mysqli` and `pdo` you can use prepared statements, which if used correctly handle the quoting for you.

A prepared example would be

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = ?");
$result->execute(array($product_id));
```

For additional reading:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29

Comment: but my product_id is always changing will the example you gave still work?

Comment: Yes, it is  a variable so it would have the variables value. The `Select * from users where name = 'chris'` is just a syntax example. See the `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = '$product_id'");` also be sure to use the `escaping` because if that contains a quote it will fail again because that will close the string encapsulation.

Comment: Hi may i know which part of the code do i replace with the example you gave me?

Comment: The line I posted 12 minutes ago is the first line of your code; `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = '$product_id'");` with the missing quotes.

Comment: Hi very sorry but i am still not sure of what to add and change. Is it possible for you to help me modify the code on your side?

Comment: What do you mean? The first line of your code, did you change it?